# Django загрузка больше постов при нажатии кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

Хочу реализовать загрузку следующих постов в новостях при нажатии кнопки с помощью ajax.
Пока получилось догружать одинаковое кол-во постов при нажатии. Т.е. сразу вижу 5 , потом нажал вывелось еще 5. И т.д. Хочу сделать так чтобы после первых 5 постов подгружались дальше уже не по 5, а по 8. Но никак не получается.
views

```
class NewsView(ListView):
    template_name="mebelain/news.html"
    queryset = News.objects.all().order_by("-date_news")

class NewsJsonListView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        upper = kwargs.get('num_news')
        lower = upper - 5
        all_news = list(News.objects.values()[lower:upper])
        return JsonResponse({'all_news':all_news})
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('news', views.NewsView.as_view(),name='news'),
  path('json_news/<int:num_news>/', views.NewsJsonListView.as_view(),name = "json_news")
]
```

js

```js
let visible = 5

const hadleGetData = () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: `/json_news/${visible}/`,
    type: 'get',
    success: function(response) {
      const data = response.all_news
      data.map(news => {
        console.log(news.id)
      })
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })
}

hadleGetData()
window.addEventListener("load", News)

function News() {
  const loadBtn = document.getElementById('load-btn')
  loadBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    visible += 5
    hadleGetData()
  })
}
```

Что мне надо поправить чтобы можно было подгружать посты так как написано выше?